# How to enter edit mode in next cell when I hit "Enter", instead of just focus on the next cell?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my code:

```
       <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="xxx" Width="*" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding VialPosition,Converter={StaticResource EditableCondition}}"        
                                 Background="{Binding ExtractionIDBackgroundColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorConvert}}" 
                                 TextAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="375" 
                                 Text="{Binding ExtractionId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How to enter edit mode in next cell when I hit "Enter", instead of just focus on the next cell?

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

To do such thing you are going to need some modifications on your CellStyle and also manipulate events as BeginEdit();

Here are some good examples on how to do that, i`ve used them and they worked pretty well.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50573/An-attempt-to-make-the-Silverlight-DataGrid-simila
  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/300003/Focus-CellEditTemplate-on-selection-of-Silverlight

These examples have all the code you need. You`ll just need some modifications to fit your software.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey Vinicius, thank you for reply. It does works fine to meed my demand mentioned above. And yet, there is another situation. I have binding the IsReadOnly and Background to a converter, to disable the first row. So, is there anyway I can disable the first row of the cells and edit the rest of them in the way I asked for above?

Comment: First, if it helped, could you accept as answer? (Thanks) Second, I believe that you have to create different styles for each behavior you expect from your cells. For example, create a style that disables a row and give it to the first one, then apply another style (which does what the above mentioned functions).

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `BeginEdit()`.  The Link for this information is [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Link only answers are a [poor practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) generally.  Try fleshing out the idea with relation to the OP's question

Comment: @paqogomez the OP showed no research.  I supplied them with the Method to use and the documentation to read.  They should not be spoon fed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);               
    }
}
```

You might find some use on the [WPF tips and tricks](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing&ProjectName=wpf) editing also